# Ideas for Economical Weapons of Mass Destruction?

Tags: science-based, weapons, aliens

Basically in my story There is an alien race that is trying to destroy humanity. Instead of wasting the energy for an invasion or some kind of super weapon they just broadcast schematics and instructions for incredibly powerful yet reasonably simple, cheap, and easily constructed weapons of mass destruction (or similarly destructive or disruptive technological devices intended to upset the balance of power on our planet.) the Idea is that we are too immature and short sighted as a race and will simply destroy ourselves with the toys they give us.

Basically the world governments and several large terror groups are in a sprint to complete the devices and weapons being broadcast to try to get an edge over each other and the world draws closer to destroying itself with each device or weapon completed. I would prefer ideas for more hard-science devices as opposed to hand-wavey "technology is basically magic" type fluff.

A few ideas I've already had: 
-Laser-radio wave-microwave type broadcast devices that excite brain tissue and cause any living animal above a selected mass to suffer seizures and strokes.

-Custom tailored biological or chemical agents that only effect people of a specific genome group (IE can be tailored to effect only certain nationalities or specific family groups)

-Some sort of wide-focus quantum particle beam (Muons? gluons?) That can be used to initiate partial-fission on nuclear fissile material rendering an opponents nuclear weapons useless.

-ultra-economical gen-mod biological weapons that are cheap. Breed a plague in your basement type refinements on our current weapons technology.

Things of that nature. The idea is to create a world where terrifying WMD's are literally everywhere, and even white supremacists or Islamic extremists can tune in and begin their own development programs. I need a laundry list of reasonably possible dooms-day devices since the story relies on this alien race broadcasting us an endless stream of ways to kill ourselves.

Comment: *"I would prefer ideas for more hard-science devices as opposed to hand-wavey "technology is basically magic" type fluff" ......... "Custom tailored biological or chemical agents that only effect people of a specific genome group (IE can be tailored to effect only certain nationalities or specific family groups)"* make up your mind.

Comment: Douglas Adams did it more simply: See [Shoe Event Horizon](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Shoe_Event_Horizon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming certain theories are correct, the ultimate WMD would be to create stable particles of "[strange" matter](https://infogalactic.com/info/Strange_matter), which are made by putting "strange" quarks together rather than the usual combinations of "up" and "down" quarks which make ordinary matter.

Strange quarks and strange matter are predicted to theoretically exist at the cores of Neutron stars, and most theories about strange matter suggest it will decay once removed from the extreme environment of a neutron star. However, it is theorized that strange matter could be stable at zero pressure, creating "[strangelets](https://infogalactic.com/info/Strangelet)"

Strange matter would have the property of [catalytically converting normal matter to strange matter](https://infogalactic.com/info/Strangelet#Dangers), so the moment a strangelet contacted normal matter, the conversion process would begin, and only stop if there was no further matter to convert. This means it would be the ultimate WMD, with a minuscule amount being able to destroy the entire planet.

The Aliens might not even give us strangelets as weapons, but simply provide the plans for highly efficient [wakefield accelerators](https://infogalactic.com/info/Plasma_acceleration) which can act as ultra compact particle beam accelerators. IF the energy is high enough, it is theoretically possible to start [creating strange matter](https://infogalactic.com/info/Strangelet#Accelerator_production) in a particle accelerator, and the destruction of Earth is virtually guaranteed at that point.